# Strange behaviour on select(2) timeout

Tags: android, android-ndk, pjsip

checking pjsip's socket select's performance, I've found a really strange behaviour with the timeout. The source code in socket_select.c is the following:

```
struct timeval os_timeout, *p_os_timeout;

PJ_CHECK_STACK();

PJ_ASSERT_RETURN(sizeof(pj_fd_set_t)-sizeof(pj_sock_t) >= sizeof(fd_set),
                 PJ_EBUG);

if (timeout) {
os_timeout.tv_sec = timeout->sec;
os_timeout.tv_usec = timeout->msec * 1000;
p_os_timeout = &os_timeout;
} else {
p_os_timeout = NULL;
}

return select(n, PART_FDSET_OR_NULL(readfds), PART_FDSET_OR_NULL(writefds),
      PART_FDSET_OR_NULL(exceptfds), p_os_timeout);
```

I've checked, and all parameters passed to select function are correct and timeout value is always re-initialized to the proper value after selection. n if also set to the maximum used file descriptor.

The problem is that, sometimes, the timeout is fired properly and exits with 0 but, sometimes, it gets blocked for a random amount of time (from some msecs to minutes), also returning 0.

I'm currently checking the contents in every fd_set, just in case, but I would really appreciate if someone has any idea of what can be going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The problem very likely is not in socket_select.c. Where are you calling the select from? Are you using multiple threads and calling select from another thread? Can you post your code or provide a link?

Comment: The source code is just pjsip's 1.x branch revision 4109. This is the code for pj_sock_select that is called from ioqueue_select.c (in pj_ioqueue_poll).
On the other hand, I've created a basic select test application and I see that, when there's socket activity I also get some delays in the timeout (not so big, around 7 or 8 milliseconds). So, I think, there should be an issue in Android's select implementation.

Comment: I remember there was a patch for building PJSIP 1.8.10 using Android NDK. http://lists.pjsip.org/pipermail/pjsip_lists.pjsip.org/2011-October/013409.html. See if your version of PJSIP also needs a patch Are you using the latest version of Android-NDK? Do you see any difference if you use PJSIP 2.x?

Comment: Thank for the link but I'm already using this patch plus few other improvements. I'm not using latest NDK but 7 and I'll give a try to PJSIP 2.0 asap but source code around sockets is the same that in 1.8. On the other hand, I've checked Android's common kernel source code and, I think, the problem can be in select's actual implementation if file operation's poll callback gets blocked. I'm trying to work around this but with no luck by now :-(